# Facebook graph api to post feed on future date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How to post new feed on future date using graph API. If I add date in published in sense its throwing error as " with message: (#100) Param published must be a boolean "

```
    if ( $session ) { try {
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'POST',
    '/me/feed',
    array (
        'message' => 'Hi friends .... ',
        'published' => "26/07/2015",
    )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($graphObject); echo "</pre>";

    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
        // echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `published` field IS a boolean, so it can only be `true` or `false`.

Btw, scheduling posts is only possible for Pages, there is no `published` parameter for `/me/feed`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed#publish

For a Page, you would set `published` to true and use a date in the `scheduled_publish_time` field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#publish